# Saving username/password for a website in iPhone keychain

Tags: iphone, passwords, keychain, autologin

Is it possible that I can save password for some website in [Keychain](http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code). Like if you open Gmail in safari iOS and select remember me, it logs in automatically.

any workaround?

thank you.

al

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GenericKeychain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html) Apple sample app with the changes I outline in the answer to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891562/ios-keychain-services-only-specific-values-allowed-for-ksecattrgeneric-key).

Comment: I guess GenericKeychain is valid after 3.2 sdk, but i have 3.1, have OS 10.5 :(

Comment: The [Keychain Services Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000898) states that it is available in iOS 2.0 and later.  You can probably take pieces of code out of GenericKeychain to make your code work.  On a side note, you may want to consider getting Snow Leopard...

Comment: I don't see that where i would spevify that i am goin to save this password info for this server/website? is it kSecAttrService or kSecAttrAccount?

Comment: don't mind my Qs, i am newbie, 2 days old in this iOS app dev.

Comment: kSecAttrService and kSecAttrAccount together identify a unique keychain item, you need to specify at least one.  To recommend two keys to use for username password, you can use kSecAttrDescription for username and kSecValueData for the password.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `NSURLCredential`, it will save both username and password in the keychain.

See my detailed answered on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17997943/249869.