# How to manage cookies when application killed in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, cookies, afnetworking

In my application i am maintaining session in serverside and it is valid for 20 days. The problem is when the app gets killed, sometimes the cookies got deleted so its asking to login again. How can I catch the event when the app gets killed so that i can save that cookie.

Comment: How are you managing cookie storage?

Comment: Actually i am using AFNetworking in my project it will manage the cookies

Comment: AFNetworking stores cookies for the lifetime of the application (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8627013/1445366).  How do you know they're getting deleted?

Comment: If the cookies are being deleted, you're deleting them from `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]`.

Comment: @AaronBrager i did not delete the cookies

Comment: @AaronBrager some times application asking me to login again when application gets crashed

Comment: Show your login code.  What else might be different?