# Access to web service with password from iOS application

Tags: ios, json, web-services, passwords

I want to get json data from web service witch requires a permission to access, when I type the url of the web service it asks me to enter a username and a password, I didn't know how to pass these two parameters in my code in xcode, I tried doing it like this but it didn't work, any ideas please

```
NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://firstluxe.com/api/search/search?query=vogue&language=1&output_format=JSON"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"OAuth %@", password] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error: &error];

NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"Response : %@", JSONDictionary);
```

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102373/afnetworking-2-0-and-http-basic-authentication) - hope it helps!

Comment: Please do not forget to up-vote the comment it it helped you. :)

Comment: please how to do it ?

Comment: Hover over my comment you'll see 'up' image on the left side of the comment right above 'flag' image, click on 'up' image.

Please take some time to read stackoverflow documentation for basics. :)

Comment: Yes I know but I didn't see the up image

Comment: Oh sorry, you need 20 points to do that, my bad.