# How to call an OAuth 2.0 API from iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, oauth-2.0, afnetworking, fitbit

I am working on [Fitbit](http://www.fitbit.com/) integration. How can I make request and authorize its OAuth 2.0 API. I checked [ASIHTTPRequest](https://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) but it is not available on ARC. Can I do it with [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking) ? I am using Objective-C.

Comment: https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/     https://omarmetwally.quora.com/Integrating-the-Fitbit-API-in-iOS-apps

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102373/afnetworking-2-0-and-http-basic-authentication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its done using `AFNetworking` using [AFOAuth2Manager](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Manager) here is the code

In ViewController.m

```
#define CLIENT_ID         @"your client id"
#define CONSUMER_SECRET      @"your consumer secret"
```

Start authorization using safari.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=227FKJ&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcallback.com%2Ffitbit&scope=activity%20nutrition%20heartrate%20location%20nutrition%20profile%20settings%20sleep%20social%20weight"]];
```

get response code from `NSUserDefaults`

```
NSString *string  = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"auth_code"];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize"];
    AFOAuth2Manager *OAuth2Manager =
    [[AFOAuth2Manager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL
                                    clientID:CLIENT_ID secret:CONSUMER_SECRET];
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"client_id":CLIENT_ID, @"grant_type":@"authorization_code",@"redirect_uri":@"http://lampdemos.com/fitbit",@"code":string};

    [OAuth2Manager authenticateUsingOAuthWithURLString:@"https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token" parameters:dict success:^(AFOAuthCredential *credential) {
        NSLog(@"Token: %@", credential.accessToken);
        AppDelegate *adddel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        adddel.credential = credential;
        [self getUserProfileWithCredentials:credential];
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

call further requests

```
-(void)getUserProfileWithCredentials:(AFOAuthCredential*)credential{
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager =
    [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithCredential:credential];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager GET:@"https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/profile.json"
      parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

             NSDictionary *dictResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
             NSDictionary *userDict  =[dictResponse valueForKey:@"user"];
            NSLog(@"Success: %@", userDict);
             NSMutableString *str =[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@""];
             for (NSString *key in [userDict allKeys]) {
                 [str appendFormat:@"%@ %@\n",key,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userDict valueForKey:key]]];
             }
             self.profileDetails.text =str;

         }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
         }];
}
```