# Keychain or NSUserDefaults? Which one to use?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, keychain

Can you suggest a good, safe way to save and show the username and password of the user so they can be shown on the login page?

I know that using NSUserDefaults is not very secure so it's not a good way to use it for storing the password for accessing my app.

Can you tell me which third-party **(in Objective-C)** methods and libraries can I use to ensure safe results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **NSURLCredential**, it will save username and password in the keychain in just two lines of code.

[This is detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17997943/5397625)

Comment: I do not understand how to remove a credential ... do I need a web address to manage loginProtectionSpace as in the example?

Comment: I'd +1000 if I could... I've been using the Keychain Services API since I began as an iOS dev with iOS 3. How I've never been aware of `NSURLCredential` I'll never know! Thanks!