# Store a private key in a persistent memory location in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am generating an RSA private key in iOS and want to have access to it between successive runs of the application. It seems to be impossible to save a SecKeyRef type in persistent memory so I was wondering if there is any other way to be able to save and load a secKeyRef private key in NSUserDefaults. I also tried to store the privateKey in the keychain and get it back as a SecKeyRef with no luck.

Any suggestions on how to store a private key in a persistent memory location in iOS?

Answer (score 3):

Storing anything at a persistent memory location is not possible and `NSDefaults` is not secure.

Apple's KeyChain is made for exactly this purpose. Have a look at the official [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1).

[SSKeyChain](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain) provides a great and easy to use wrapper for KeyChain APIs.

Comment: Additionally, there are a number of existing questions on StackOverflow you might find helpful, such as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670647/adding-private-key-into-ios-keychain

Comment: Firstly, I do not care about security at this point since I am doing some tests, plus it is in a memory variable for some time so it is still insecure even if I manage to store it in the Keychain. Second, I have tried to store it in the keychain but when trying to get it back as SecKeyref i get a null reference. Do not point me in existing posts because I have done a fair amount of investigation.

Comment: Keychain is the correct place to store this. If you are having trouble using keychain, then you should post a question on that with details of your problem. There is no other place that is designed to store private keys in iOS.

Comment: I have no problem storing it in the keychain. My problem is getting it back from the keychain as a SecKeyRef.

Comment: Why don't you ask a new question about your specific SecKeyRef problem so that somebody here can help you out with that?

Comment: OK, new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443707/store-rsa-private-key-and-get-it-back-as-a-seckeyref

Answer (score -3):

***Not secured solution***

You can use NSUserDefaults like this :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: privateKey forkey:@"myKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And retrieve it with :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```

***by the way***

to store an int value, use setInteger: instead of setObject

Comment: This is a terrible idea if you're storing a private key that is presumably very sensitive. `NSUserDefaults` is not encrypted, and absolutely not secure.