# adding key to Key Chain Item

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

So this is my first question on Stack Overflow and it's about keychain so, I read apple documentation about keychain and they mention that the key can be generated or obtain by other means "which is my case" then I created "query dictionary" like they said ,but when I tried to add it I get  an error and my **status is equal to -50** I don't know what does than mean also the reason I am trying to store my key is so I can use it with **"SecKeyDecrypt"** to decrypt messages which require SecKey as parameter

UPDATE: I found that what the return code means -50 errSecParam which mean 
**"One or more parameters passed to the function are not valid."**  then I try to remove my **kSecValueRef as String: privateKey**
and it works but still, I want that key to be stored ??

```
 let privateKey = "myKey"

    let tag = "mybunlde.com".data(using: .utf8)!

        let addPrivateKey: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
                                            kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: tag,
                                            kSecValueRef as String: privateKey]
        let status = SecItemAdd(addPrivateKey as CFDictionary, nil)
        guard status == errSecSuccess else { print("error while creating the key")
            return
        }

        let getPrivateKey: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
                                            kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: tag,
                                            kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                                            kSecReturnRef as String: true]

        print("getPrivateKey \(getPrivateKey)")
    } else {
        print("no key found ")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this lib for store & retrieve data from keychain 
https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper

e.g

```
let save: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set("hello keychain", forKey: "key_name")
let get: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "key_name")
```

Comment: SecKeyDecrypt requires parameter of try secKey and the lib return it as string?

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_keychain?language=objc

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8993/how-can-i-add-a-private-key-to-my-keychain
[Adding private key into iOS Keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670647/adding-private-key-into-ios-keychain)

use above link.....

Comment: this is for object C and I am using swift? and I have read an article smaller to it https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_keychain