# iOS keychain wrapper NSInternalInconsitity Exception

Tags: ios, keychain

I am using the keychain wrapper at (As recommended on another thread)

https://gist.github.com/1170641

Code causing error:

```
//Save username + password to keychain
KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc]     initWithIdentifier:@"PHP POS" accessGroup:nil];

[keychainItem setObject:username forKey:@"username"];
[keychainItem setObject:password forKey:@"password"];
```

Exception:

```
2013-01-28 14:51:09.531 PHP POS[21078:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[KeychainItemWrapper writeToKeychain], /Users/cmuench/Desktop/PHP-Point-Of-Sale-Repos/PHP-Point-Of-Sale-iOS/KeychainWrapper/KeychainItemWrapper.m:305
2013-01-28 14:51:09.532 PHP POS[21078:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't add the Keychain Item.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13be012 0x1186e7e 0x13bde78 0xc1cf35 0x233e4 0x22859 0x34ec 0x4ef0 0x48e2 0x19f37b 0x1a8048 0x24c9bf 0x2534df 0x252fec 0x251f5e 0x25c076 0xdf43b 0x1dce05 0x1dce05 0x1dce05 0x1dce05 0xdf495 0xdee66 0xdf24b 0xd0cf8 0x225fdf9 0x225fad0 0x1333bf5 0x1333962 0x1364bb6 0x1363f44 0x1363e1b 0x225e7e3 0x225e668 0xce65c 0x255d 0x2485)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

NOTE: I am runnning this in the simulator.

Comment: The keychain is usable only on devices, as the simulator has no keychain.

Comment: @Echihl That is not true, there is a keychain in the simulator.  It works a little differently, but it is there and usable.

Comment: The only difference with the keychain on the simulator vs device is that you can't use accessgroups in the simulator.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that @"username" and @"password" are not valid key values.

You have to use one from the [Keychain Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

That code won't work, it will run into the same issues I ran into when I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891562/ios-keychain-services-only-specific-values-allowed-for-ksecattrgeneric-key).  Check out the answer I found and the other answer who ARCified my answer, it should help you out.