# how to use keychain example from apple docs

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, keychain

I am trying to store and retrieve a string value to my keychain, I have been using the example found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1) however when I call mySetObject method my app is crashing.

This is what the code looks like that I am using to access the keychain class method mySetObject

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Test keychain Wrapper for future use through out connectionClasses
    KeychainWrapper *keychainWrapper = [[KeychainWrapper alloc] init];

    // set key
    [keychainWrapper mySetObject:@"myObj" forKey:@"entry1"]; // this is where my app falls over

    // read key

    NSString *myAwesomeID = [keychainWrapper myObjectForKey:@"myObj"];
    NSLog(@"%@", myAwesomeID);

//..
```

the error I am reciving in my output is as follows

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't add the Keychain Item.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't simply use keychain as a dictionary. It works only with predefined sets of keys. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/5008417/653513 and an answer below that shows ARC usage: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14243924/653513

Comment: this link helped me. http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/using-the-keychain-to-store-passwords-on-ios I didnt realise I was to use the speial list of functions (not sure if thats the right word for them... but for example this kSecAttrAccount

Answer (score 0):

This wrapper (KeychainItemWrapper) is similar to an NSDictionary, you set values for keys, however you don’t get to choose the keys. Please refer [blog posting](http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/using-the-keychain-to-store-passwords-on-ios)

So can't do:

```
// set key
[keychainWrapper mySetObject:@"myObj" forKey:@"entry1"]; // this is where my app falls over
```

Comment: thanks that helped me. also when using KeychainWrapper hopefully this helps someone, i noticed i need to 'bridge cast' the keys, because the compiler generates warnings, unless you do [keychain mySetObject:@"mypassword" forKey:(__bridge NSString *)kSecValueData];